# Searchbar for UITableView as subview of UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

In my app, I have several controllers with arrays and search functions. These arrays are displayed in tables and the search works fine.

HOWEVER, I am trying to create a universal search on my app's main page. This would search ALL the arrays (I don't mind combining them as a single array in the main page view controller). I have tried many ways to accomplish this but continue to hit blocks. The furthest I have got is the searchbar showing, but then it crashes everytime I try to search.

I don't have any code to show as I've not got anything that will work. Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this? Any tutorials etc?

The main tutorial I used to set up the several individual pages is: http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view

EDIT:
I have added an image to demonstrate what I need.

So I have 3 UITableViews, all accessible view buttons from the main UIViewController. Each UITableView then has an associated array to itself, TableView Array 2, 3 and 4.

Search Bar 2 searches through TableView Array 2
Search Bar 3 searches through TableView Array 3
Search Bar 4 searches through TableView Array 4

Now I have Search Bar 1 on the main UIViewController. I want this search bar to search through ALL the arrays (2, 3 and 4). I don't mind combining all the array data in to a single array which is present in the UIViewController file, but I can't find a way to get the search to work.

Image:
http://s14.postimg.org/o5z1e5j75/Untitled_1.png

Comment: What is the principal difference between searching in 1 array or two or three?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: I am trying to understand what is your problem if you have a working search for each separate array of data but hitting blocks while searching across all three of them. It's very hard to suggest anything at this point as there is no code.

Comment: You need to explain your problem more clearly, even add images and or drawings if your can.

Comment: Edited with an image and longer description!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need a single universal implementaion of searching and displaying content from 3 different arrays. So, in this case I usualy create base controller class, that will have search bar and tableView, all searching function, and pointer to datasource array.
*typing direct in browser, so there can be errors.*

```
@interface BaseListController : UIViewController
{
UITableView* _tableView;
UISearchBar* _searchBar;
}
@property NSArray * source;
@poperty (readonly) NSArray * founded;
@end;
```

than, you need to make sure that objects from all of 3 your arrays support you special searching interface:

```
@protocol SearchedItem <NSObject>
@required
- (NSString *)searchKey;
@end
```

after this your searching method will look like:

```
- (void)searchForKey:(NSString *)searchText
{
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"searchKey contains[cd] %@", searchText];
_founded = [self.source filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

[_tableView reloadData];
}
```

**EDIT:** *Expanded answer how and why need to use @protocol*

First of all read [this aticle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html), its clearly explains how to use @protocol.
I still dont know what you will keep in those 3 arrays. But lets say you will keep there objects of 3 different classes inherited fom NSObject, and lets call them `Chapter`, `Recipe` and `Ingredient`. Each of them will has thier own unique proprty names. And for handling their mixes independently this classes must have something common. This common thing will be single interface - all of them must conforms your defined @protocol. This means,  it's no matter this object's class, but you can sure that it will respond to called protocol's method. Code example:

```
// .h file
@interface Chapter : NSObject <SearchedItem>
@property NSString * chapterName;
@property NSArray * recipes;
@end

@interface Recipe : MSObject <SearchedItem>
@property NSString * recipeName;
@property NSArray * ingredients;
@end

@interface Ingredient : NSObject <SearchedItem>
@property NSString * prettyName;
@property NSNumber * enoughCount;
@end

// .m file There you must implement protocol's requied method!
@implementation Chapter
- (NSString *)searchKey{
return self.chapterName;
}
@end

@implementation Recipe 
- (NSString *)searchKey{
return self.recipeName;
}
@end

@implementation Ingredient 
- (NSString *)searchKey{
return self.prettyName;
}
@end
```

so now, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you can easy get row title without knowing what data you currently show:

```
id<SearchedItem> item = self.source; //self.founded
cell.titleLabel.text = [item searchKey];
```

P.S. if you storing simple NSStrings in your arrays, you dont need any protocols

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you possibly provide me with more information in terms of the code? I'm relatively new to this and just not sure about the 3 arrays part. Where am I including that code? In the base controller or in the individual TableViews with their arrays?

Comment: Basically, all  code above must be in base controller. You can then create 3 instance of this class, and just set 3 different arrays of objects. Or create 3 subclasses of this base class, but you should do it if only you want to setup your tableView with different cells or this viewController will has rarely different behavior

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Could you just explain this bit a little more the @protocol bit a little more?

Comment: i had expanded my answer, check it

Comment: I just can't seem to get this to work. I think I must be missing something in the code, is this the full layout?

Comment: yes, this is pretty full layout. Let's try come from other side, what do you store in arrays 2, 3 and 4? I will explain my approach based on your solution